# Eclipse not recognizing Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependencies

I am new to Gradle and I was trying this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
I was able to compile the jar with the required dependencies and run it.
However, I find it annoying that the libraries are not recognized by the IDE.

[image]

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: I'm guessing that your IDE is Eclipse. Install the Buildship eclipse plugin, and follow its instructions to load a gradle project into Eclipse. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration

Comment: My IDE is the Spring Tool Suite and as far as I know it is not necessary to download it.

Comment: Then just follow its instructions. You must have something like File - import - gradle project or something like that.

Comment: Is your Eclipse project a Gradle project or just a plain Java project? If Gradle, right-click project and select "Gradle (STS)" > "Refresh All". If not Gradle, right-click project and select "Configure" > "Convert to Gradle (STS) Project".

Comment: It is solved, as JB Nizet suggested Buildship is necessary and the project needed to be transformed to Gradle as Andreas said. Thank you all

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should use the gradle eclipse plugin. Add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "eclipse"
```

This will add eclipse related tasks to your build. By executing

```
gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse
```

Gradle will regenerate all eclipse project and classpath files based on the current dependencies of your project(s). You will however need to refresh your IDE to make the changes visible.

There is one more thing to consider. As eclipse is not really aware of the gradle dependencies - it knows them only by the generated classpath files - new dependencies will be visible to eclipse only after regenerating these files. Furthermore dependencies added in eclipse will not be visible to your gradle build and will be removed once the classpath files are regenerated.

Comment: The script should actually be `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` (no `w` should be in there), tried to edit, but since it wasn't 6 characters I was blocked

Comment: @NateH06 `gradlew` is correct. This is the gradle wrapper (can be created with `gradle wrapper`). By using the wrapper you are not tied to a globally installed gradle version but can specify the gradle version with your source code.

Comment: Ah, got it. I didnt have that set up, so it didn't work.

Comment: `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse` this works awesome. Thanks for this info. Note: if `gradlew` is not work for you, we can try `gradle`.

Comment: what about enviroment. should I keep it locally or can I push it to git. What I meant to say, if from a machine where eclipse is not there & I run this command or 'gradle clean build -x Test', will it throw error?

Comment: @PSatishPatro It’s save to push this to SCM. First the eclipse tasks won’t be executed, if you simply build your repo (at least if your build is configured properly), second there is no dependency on any eclipse binaries or resources in these tasks.

Comment: Follow this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171471/eclipse-not-recognizing-gradle-dependencies/63228389#63228389

Answer (score 30):

What worked for me is :

right-click the build.gradle file -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies.

Comment: Great. I would prefer this over the [Eclipse Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html); the latter one may confuse my colleagues who use Gradle without Eclipse. It should be the IDE's job to understand the build script. It feels really weird to mention Eclipse in build script which do not actually rely on Eclipse at all.

Comment: wow. Eclipse confuses me sooo much. Thanks though, this was anything but clear to me.

Comment: @mtpain - I spent half a day on this issue as well.  I don't understand why eclipse can't just refresh the dependencies automatically once the build.gradle file is changed.

Comment: Refresh Gradle Project was the only option available to me under Gradle, and this worked.

Comment: Thank you.  The last thing I wanted to do was change the project configuration to work on my system when it works on everyone else's system just fine.

Comment: Follow this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171471/eclipse-not-recognizing-gradle-dependencies/63228389#63228389

Answer (score 18):

After importing the project as a Java project, in Eclipse Neon you:

```
Right-click on your project --> Configure --> Add Gradle Nature.
```

Your project will automatically refresh and you will see all the dependencies being downloaded by Gradle.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on mac do what dpr mentioned. That is add the following in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "eclipse"
```

Then run the following:

```
gradle cleanEclipse eclipse
```

Answer (score 7):

**Enable** auto build gradle using below settings to avoid this issue

Go to Eclipse/STS in Windows -> Preference -> Gradle, Click Gradle Workspace Settings, there Enable **Auto project synchronization**

It automatically refreshes the Gradle when **saving** the changes in **build.gradle** file.

[image]

Finally, click  `Project -> Clean-> choose your project` and click `Clean` button

Answer (score 4):

In eclipse 
**Window -> preference -> Gradle** 
in dependency management section 
**check on -> remap jar to Gradle projects.** 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a bug from the IDE's. I encounter this Gradle dependencies problem in both the Eclipse and Spring tool suite.

My sincere suggestion is that first try this, right-click the build.gradle file -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies.

If this does not work, Best and working solution is
1) Do gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies from the command prompt. Then create a new workspace and IMPORT the project into this workspace.

2) If the above thing failed, then in worst-case scenario one need to make a git clone of the project into a new folder and follow the above method.

Answer (score 1):

Add the two classpath variables GRADLE_HOME and GRADLE_REPO in eclipse in the below location:

```
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables
```

`GRADLE_HOME` to be set to the Gradle Installation directory

`GRADLE_REPO` to be set to the cache folder inside .gradle  (EXAMPLE :  C:\users\user1\.gradle\caches :This location jars will be saved from repo.

Once the variables are set make sure build.gradle has the proper plugin defined depending on the eclipse version you are using:

```
apply plugin 'eclipse'
apply plugin 'eclipse-wtp'
```

Use the below configuration in build.gradle to resolve deployment issue:

```
eclipse {
    wtp {
        component {
            libConfigurations += [configurations.runtimeClasspath]
        }
    }
}
```

Then follow the below steps:

```
Project -> clean
Right click on the Project ->Gradle ->Refresh Gradle Project
```

If the above steps doesn't resolve the issue it is advise to check if the build process is able to download the jars from artifactory/nexus as due to authentication error or wrong url of artifactory/nexus jar download fails.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue :
1)right-click the build.gradle file -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies.

[image]

2)if this didnt help (happened to me )
Project -> Clean-> choose your project and press "Clean"
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

> eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Gradle -> "Select Local
> Installation Directory"
>
> Click on Browse button and provide path for Gradle directory

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem importing Gradle projects from TFS. Unless the initial import uses the Gradle importer the build.gradle will not be setup. You have to remove the project from the Eclipse workspace (do not delete on disk) and then import the project again as a Gradle project. This updates the build path according to **build.gradle**

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened recently when I updated my whole OS and lost my configuration plugins from Eclipse.

It turns out, my projects (libraries sometimes) use Lombok, so the annotation processor wasn't wiring everything as I was expecting it. I did what [this guide](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) suggested and it worked (In addition to quitting and opening Eclipse, as the prompted restart doesn't quite work)