# Eclipse not able to recognise annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea, annotations

I have checked out a gradle project in eclipse but it is not able to recognise any annotation.Foe every annotation in each file it says

```
Configuration cannot be resolved to a 
 type
```

where configuration is annotation.

and all imports corresponding to annotation are also failing with following error:

```
The import org.springframework cannot be resolved
```

Entire project with all files is filled with error. But there is no such problem like this in Intellij for same project. Which setting am I missing for Eclipse ?

gradle build works fine although

Comment: you are missing those libraries in your path

Comment: Your Eclipse instance is probably not able to understand Gradle projects out of the box. You might need to install a Gradle plugin (if not already present) and import the project as a Gradle project to tell Eclipse to actually read and use the gradle configuration like dependencies.

Comment: Gradle nature is there already .

Comment: gradle build works fine for me,so it is not gradle problem.I have added gradle nature to eclipse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171471/eclipse-not-recognizing-gradle-dependencies/38171826 has resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I did not see a checkout option in Eclipse for a Gradle project. I'm using Eclipse version 2019-06 (4.12.0). You need to check out the project in to your local file system and then do an import of the existing project as a Gradle Project.

Things to Note:

1. Make sure you have the Gradle buildship plugin installed in your Eclipse. (The plugin I use. Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle, provided as part of the Gradle Platform.)
2. Go to File --> Import. When a pop up box opens, scroll down to Gradle and select Existing Gradle project.

[image]

This Way Eclipse recognises the Gradle Project.

Comment: i opend a project from file system. And then right click on project => add gradle nature.

Comment: in my build path ,in the libraries section,i cannot see "Project and external Dependencies",i think it may be the problem. Do u know how to add it?

Comment: Is your project a Gradle Project? Gradle Projects should be imported differently on eclipse. I have updated my answer. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: yes its a gradle project. I generally git clone repo to my local and then import into eclipse and then right click and select "Add gradle nature", Its same as what you are doing.I have been doing it for long .It works fine.I have checkout out one version and working on it for 2 weeks ,now because of some problem, i need to checkout the original version again.but when i import it.i see all annotation errors.although the version in which i have my changes works fine